# Error: Could not find info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5

Tags: android

I am migrating my old project to the latest API Level. While doing so I updated the dependencies to the recommended versions. While running a gradle build I am stuck at

```
 What went wrong:     

 Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    > Could not find info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5.
  Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/info/androidhive/barcode-reader/1.1.5/barcode-reader-1.1.5.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/info/androidhive/barcode-reader/1.1.5/barcode-reader-1.1.5.pom
  Required by:
     project :app
```

Below are the dependencies included in the gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/meltag/hil/util/libs/jsoup-1.10.2.jar')
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1') {
        exclude module: 'gson:2.2.4'
    }
    implementation 'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Before the project was built for Android 10 and was never updated. Now the app is not listed on the Play Store due to the sdk gap. I want to target 31 and above so that I can rebuild the app and publish it.

How can I resolve this dependency issue? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use this library.
For easier use, be sure to clone the example and check it.

[barcode scanner](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)